# Background Image overflow

Tags: css

Am trying to do something like the following:

```
ul {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 16px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    z-index: 1000;
    background-image: url(arrow.png);
    background-position: -10px -10px;
}

<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
</ul>
```

Now my problem is that I cant get the arrow to jut out from the rounded white box. Something like a tooltip. I do not want to use an extra div or other elements. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best I've managed is this:

```
ul 
{
    display: block;
    margin-top: 16px;
    padding-left: 10px; /* pad for size of arrow image */
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
    z-index: 1000;
    background:url("arrow.png") no-repeat top left;
}

ul li
{
    margin:0; padding:0;
    list-style-type:none;
    background-color:white;
    width:60px; /* fiddle with sizing for box */
}

ul li:first-child
{
    border-radius: 0px 5px 0px 0px;
}

ul li:last-child
{
    border-radius: 0px 0px 5px 5px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this with javascript, possibly easiest with jQuery 'wrap' to put extra divs around your li tags which you can then style up with css.

Comment: How is this not using extra elements?

Comment: The extra elements do not have to be hard-coded in the list, which is helpful if the list is manually entered, or even if it is pulled from a db and generated with e.g. PHP. The styling and content are still separate and although extra elements are present in the rendered page they are generated in-browser and do not have to be put into the content directly. Hence 'not using extra elements'.